# Can conda automatically activate the env from an env environment.yml?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

This my environment.yml:

```
name: my-env-name
dependencies:
  - blah
```

To create this env I can cd to the dir with the yml in it and do this:

```
conda env create
```

Conda's smart enough to look in the yml and see the env name.

But to activate it why do I have to do this:

```
source activate my-env-name
```

Is there a switch to have conda just activate the env name from the environment.yml?

Comment: Did you mean `source activate my-env-name` in the last code bit?

Comment: yup just changed it thanks

Comment: I don't think there's a switch, but you could chain the commands `conda env create -f environment.yml && source activate my-env-name`

Comment: the point is Id like to avoid having to type the environment name in the command anywhere, if its already defined in the yml.

Comment: Well, then as far as I know, the answer to your question in the post is "No" and the answer to your title question is "Because no one has added that feature" :-)

Comment: edited my post title to be clearer

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. Workaround: [direnv](https://direnv.net/) with anaconda [layout](https://github.com/direnv/direnv/wiki/Python#anaconda)